# Is Agile different from TDD ? If so what are the main differences?

Tags: tdd, agile

Is Agile really different from TDD ? If so what are the main differences ?

Comment: TDD is development specific whereas agile refers more to the project style (although I get what you're asking). TDD can be a great development practice WHEN USED CORRECTLY. Use TDD from the beginning with waterfall and incorporate it at the end in agile. As an extra, look at [BDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development) because there are many times when it will outweigh TDD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development

In short, TDD and Agile really focus on different aspects, and aren't mutually exclusive of one another.

- TDD is very focused on how code gets written (and thus tends to be aimed at the work cycles of individual or small groups of developers exclusively).
- Agile is really focused on the overall development process, not just how the code gets written and tested (and thus focuses a lot on project management and groups of developers, as opposed to specifically how a given developer writes code).

Answer (score 9):

Agile is anything that is inline with the values listed here - http://agilemanifesto.org/

XP ([Extreme Programming](http://www.extremeprogramming.org/)) is a methodology that qualifies as agile. There are others too (Scrum, Crystal, etc..)

TDD (Test Driven Development) is a specific engineering practice from XP - which is a way to write code + drive design in incremental chunks. You write a test first, make it pass with the simplest possible change and then refactor to improve the structure/design. You do this in a loop till you're done.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to play devil's advocate and say, Yes. TDD and Agile are the same thing, just at different scales.

Bear with me, here.

First off, TDD encourages you to have a plan of what you want to achieve, before you achieve it. You don't think about *how* you're going to achieve it. You just think about how to demonstrate that the thing you're about to write is valuable, and you work out how you know. This is very similar to the way in which projects are ideally sourced and requirements are gathered in Agile methodologies.

Then, you do the minimum necessary to get feedback on the work. With TDD this means a red or green bar. At a higher level, Agile methodologies encourage you to showcase and get feedback from stakeholders, or (preferably) release to production and see if it works and if anyone uses it.

Then you work out what the next bit of work to do is, and you write the next bit of the plan.

Agile methodologies may also use estimation and prioritisation, but these are mostly to do with assigning budgets and working out whether the work is worth doing in the first place - which devs do naturally at a small scale.

Agile methodologies are iterative - that is, the periods of planning, implementation, delivery and feedback are cyclical. So is TDD, with exactly the same steps.

Agile methodologies usually emphasise communication, conversation and lightweight documentation. TDD can be used as a form of documentation, too, especially if you make the test-names into meaningful sentences and use the same language that the business use together with realistic examples. This can also encourage communication and conversation.

Agile methodologies encourage reflection and learning from the past. TDD has this lovely red bar which can help you to do that very quickly.

If you scale TDD up, you get Acceptance Tests or BDD-style scenarios. Further up you start getting into Feature Injection and other forms of vision-driven analysis. Further up still you're looking at whether the released project retains your market share, or provides the options you wanted going forward, or achieves whatever its original vision was. The tests get bigger, but the process of writing just enough, getting feedback on it and learning continuously is still the same, no matter what the Agile methodology is.

All the rules which help Agile to be successful at a large scale can be applied to TDD at a small scale, and vice versa. (I'm trying hard to think of any exceptions to that and can't).

So, no. Agile isn't different to TDD. It's just TDD-done-bigger.

Comment: +1, despite kind of disagreeing. You make a very good case.  But there are aspects of Agile that TDD in and of itself really doesn't touch on - I'm thinking principally of Individuals & Interactions over Processes & Tools; TDD is very much a Process, and does little in the interpersonal realm, alone - although it couples really well with Pairing, which is all about I&I.  Still - you make a good case.

Comment: Well, I'm more into BDD, which is a variant of TDD that TDDers describe as "TDD done well". In BDD we use the language of the business *in order* to enhance conversation and encourage communication, and we value it more than our tools. I'm doing a couple of sessions at Agile 2010 based around this, so thank you for the encouragement!

Comment: You make good arguements but you're wrong - if only for the reason that you don't have to do TDD to be agile or to be agile to use TDD. The case you're making is that TDD is a good example of an agile methodology and that *is* absolutely true but to say the two are the same is misleading - which is, I suspect, why this question arose in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

The differences are huge because I think there's a very simple distinction:

Agile is a philosophy whereas TDD is a specific methodology.

There are any number of ways you can work that are agile but by and large you are either doing TDD or you're not.

You can be Agile without using TDD (or a variant thereof) and you can use TDD without being agile (though I'd be somewhat surprised).